# How do I put an auto number in my google sheets without returning NaN?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

The system generates an auto number every time someone answers and submit the form (google form) and send an email stating the Inventory Number Assigned to them who answers and submit the google form. If the responses came in one by one the code and auto number works just fine. But if there is a simultaneous responses coming and and there's two person submit the form at the same time and second most likely a second or two. The auto number will then be blank and the other return as NaN then after that the auto number will start at 001. I posted with the result and also the code. Not sure what to change in the code or how will I come up with the solution. I used Google App Script. Hope you can help me. TYIA.

Here's my code:

```
    function addTestFormResponses() 
    {
      var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Test Form Responses");
      var LastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
      var AutoNumberStart = "RO -001"; 
 
      var CLCName = sheet.getRange (LastRow, 21).getValue();
      var LearnCenter = sheet.getRange (LastRow, 24).getValue();
      var DivOffice = sheet.getRange (LastRow, 4).getValue();
      var EmailAddress = sheet.getRange (LastRow, 3).getValue();
      var Subject = "The ALS CLC Inventory Number ";
    
      if (sheet.getRange(1, 1).getValue() == "Timestamp") 
      {   
        sheet.insertColumnBefore(1);
        sheet.getRange(1, 1).setValue("ALS CLC Inventory Number"); 
        sheet.getRange("A2:A").setNumberFormat(0); 
    
        if (LastRow>1)  
        {
          for(var i=2; i <= LastRow; i++) 
          {
            sheet.getRange(i, 1).setValue(AutoNumberStart);
            AutoNumberStart= "RO -00" +(parseInt(AutoNumberStart.match(/(\d+)/))+1);

            var Message = 'The ALS CLC Inventory Number assigned to ' + LearnCenter + ' ' + 
     CLCName + ',' + '<br>located in Region ' + DivOffice + ',' + ' is: <b>' + 
            ("RO -00" + (parseInt(AutoNumberStart.match(/(\d+)/)))) + '</b><br><br>Thank you!';

            MailApp.sendEmail(EmailAddress, Subject, Message, {htmlBody: Message});
       
          }
        }
      }
  
      if (sheet.getRange(LastRow, 1)) 
      {
        if (LastRow == 2) 
        {      
            sheet.getRange(LastRow, 1).setValue(AutoNumberStart)
     
            var Message = 'The ALS CLC Inventory Number assigned to ' + LearnCenter + ' ' + 
    CLCName + ',' + '<br>located in Region ' + DivOffice + ',' + ' is: <b>' + 
            ("RO -00" + (parseInt(AutoNumberStart.match(/(\d+)/)))) + '</b><br><br>Thank you!';

            MailApp.sendEmail(EmailAddress, Subject, Message, {htmlBody: Message});
        }

        else 
        {
            var LastAutoNumber = sheet.getRange(LastRow-1, 1).getValue();
            sheet.getRange(LastRow, 1).setValue("RO -00"+ 
    (parseInt(LastAutoNumber.match(/(\d+)/))+1));

            var Message = 'The ALS CLC Inventory Number assigned to ' + LearnCenter + ' ' + 
    CLCName + ',' + '<br>located in Region ' + DivOffice + ',' + ' is: <b>' + 
            ("RO -00" + (parseInt(LastAutoNumber.match(/(\d+)/)))) + '</b><br><br>Thank you!';

            MailApp.sendEmail(EmailAddress, Subject, Message, {htmlBody: Message});
        }
      }
    }
```

Here's the output.
[image]

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand the relationship between your question and your showing script. Can I ask you about the detail of your question?

Comment: Perhaps you should consider using the Lock Service

Comment: What does a Lock Service means?

Comment: My problem is that I created a Google Form linked with Google Sheets with Google App Script codes that generates an Auto Number. And that Auto Number will be sent to the respondent of the said Google Form every time they hit the submit button. however if two persons submit the form at the same time (a seconds or two) the auto numbering crash and return a NaN instead of a continuous auto number.

Comment: @Cooper: How can I insert the Lock Service in my codes? Will the respondents be able to submit simultaneously if I insert it? The Google Form will be used by more than a thousand persons and we'll be expecting 20k responses as well. Thanks you

Comment: @Cooper I already tried to use Lock Service in my codes but I don't know where exactly to put it.  I try to put it before I declare a variable its the first if statement in my codes now but its still not working. I keep on getting a blank and a NaN auto number.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm not really familiar with Google App Script. This is the first time I used it.